# Is there an equivalent of EnterFrame event in Expression Blend/WPF, If not how do we get around it?

Tags: c#, wpf, actionscript-3, expression-blend, enterframeevent

i am moving from **AS3** and Java to **Expression Blend/WPF**, but cant seem to figure out how to replicate **`EnterFrame`** event in **C#**, is there a `update()` or `frameUpdate()` function.

Answer (score 1):

this should be helpful:
http://www.shinedraw.com/mathematics/difference-on-timer-enter-frame-dispatcher-timer-and-composition-target/

and this too

http://insideria.com/2009/01/scripted-animation-in-silverli.html

Comment: +1, Silverlight handles animation very differently from Flash - arguably, more efficiently, but makes some tasks harder than in AS. Storyboards should be the way to go; however, even in Flash, framerate dependent scripting shouldn't be used unless it really is suitable for the task, and you don't care about the _actual_ time spent each frame, because it _will_ be variable. Silverlight disposes of this problem altogether by enforcing (to some extent) time-based animation/scripting.

Answer (score 0):

[CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) is called every frame. You could also use timer such as [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28VS.95%29.aspx).